# Problem connecting on Slush's pool with GUIMiner, i tried many Host adress to connect, every time it says the target computer expressly reject it

Tags: mining-pools, mining-software, connection

[image: current second problem when i shutdown guiminer]I'm on Windows 10 with GUIminer, i want to mine on the slush's pool but every time i enter every host adress i saw it didn't work on slush pool.

I entered the right login for my miner and on GUIminer it says that the target computer expressly refused it, i have Bitcoin core too and i didn't finish to download it, Bitcoin core and GUIminer are on my external drive, can this make some trouble?

the full message was "errno 10061: no connection could be established because the target computer expressly refused it"

and my second problem is need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: ah i forgot something i used the adress 'stratum+tcp://eu.stratum.slushpool.com:3333' so i think i need to used the general adress and my software bitcoin core has not finish the synchronisation so can this be a part of the problem?

Comment: Can you give us the full error message you get ?

Comment: Now, its "need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: i'm searching for the error but the error was "errno 10061" something like that.

Comment: yes i found it the error was "no connection could be established because the target computer expressly refused it" and i entered all of the current host adress and it didn't work.